# Flutter change URL manually without restarting app [WEB]

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetX as my route management in my flutter project.

I am trying to make my project dynamic so that users could navigate between pages by clicking buttons and by changing to URL route.

for example, let's assume this is my web URL:

```
www.myApp.com/
```

Then if I need to navigate to `/home` The user should only type

```
www.myApp.com/home
```

but unfortunately when I try to type a new URL and hit `ENTER` the app restarts...

How can I prevent the app to restart and open the route directly just like `Get.toNamed('/home')`